# linking chart points to textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a page with 5 text boxes that produce values from a calculation form. I would like to have a chart on this page based on the values of these text boxes so that it updates accordingly, does anyone have any idea how do this? example code would be ideal.

Many thanks.

Comment: Well, you didn't say what kind of chart, but you would have your chart on your form and update it every time one of the textbox values changed.

Comment: thanks, what code lines would i need to use to reference the chart points to = val(textbox)